# Zend get foreign ID from login table

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am using Zend and Doctrine to login using a table containing also a foreign ID to another table. I need to get this ID in order to use it in a Doctrine query (through the controller) to the database like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Lost_Model_Item i')
        ->where('i.StatID = ?', 'I need the ID here') 
        $result = $q->fetchArray();
```

I have tried to get it like this:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->ID
```

But it seems to not work. I am new to Zend and a bit lost here. Could you please help?

As I ma working with doctrine I have created an adapter as follow:

```
public function authenticate()
   {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('Lost_Model_Station u')
      ->where('u.username = ? AND u.password = MD5(?)',
                array($this->username, $this->password)
      );
$result = $q->fetchArray();
if (count($result) == 1) {
  $this->_resultArray = $result[0];
  return new Zend_Auth_Result(
    Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS, $this->username, array());
} else {
  return new Zend_Auth_Result(
    Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE, null, 
      array('Authentication unsuccessful')
  );      
}
  }
```

Comment: How do you set Identity? And when you print `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->ID` what is returned? If it is null then clearly this value does not exist!

Comment: I am trying to get the Id after checking that login is successful that is in LoginAction function...and yes the Id exists.

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->ID before you create the query, after you create it and finally to do a var_dump of the query?

Comment: var_dump gives no result. I am probably missing something somewhere!

Comment: Does `var_dump(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity());` return anything? Have you tried `Zend_Debug::dump(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity());`?

Comment: Var_dump only give the username:  string(6) username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `getIdentity` to get the username and then use a sql join on `Lost_Model_Item` and `Lost_Model_Station`

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Lost_Model_Item i')
    ->leftJoin('i.Lost_Model_Station u')
    ->where('u.username = ?', Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()) 
$result = $q->fetchArray();
```

This assumes that there is a doctrine "hasOne" relation defined for `Lost_Model_Station` (in the base class):

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasOne('Lost_Model_Item', array(
         'local' => 'StatID',
         'foreign' => 'whatever_id_StatID_relates_to'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->ID
```

well you got what you store in Identity . You need to post the code where you ask user to login . Because there you are not storing the ID inside the session storage which Zend_Auth uses . Basically do this there

```
 $row  = $this->_adapter->getResultRowObject();
 Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($row);
```

where $this->_adapter is

```
$this->_adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable();
        $this->_adapter->setTableName('users')
                       ->setIdentityColumn('email')
                       ->setCredentialColumn('password');
```

Comment: I am using Doctrine. I have created an Adapter. I have edited my question.